# EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: No type found; Types are required when writing in ES versions 6 and below. Expected [index]/[type],

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql, elasticsearch-5

Hi I am using ES version 6.6.1, While Spark writing the data in ES, throwing below Exception.

org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: No type found; Types are required when writing in ES versions 6 and below. Expected [index]/[type], but got [my_index_name]

```
df.write.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
  .option("es.mapping.id", "id")
  .mode("append").save("my_index_name")
```

Can anyone please help me here to resolve this issue.
Thanks

Comment: try `my_index_name/_doc/`

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be your ElasticSearch-spark jar package version is not matched.
If your ensure that dependency is right, then you can try it:

```
df.write
  .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
  .option("es.mapping.id", "id")
  .option("es.resource", "table/table_alias")
  .option("es.write.operation", "upsert")
  .option("es.nodes", es_node)
  .option("es.port", "80")
  .mode("append")
  .save()
```